# Are Database-as-a-Service providers like Modulus and Mongolab actually secure?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

Recently, I have been looking at the security of the customer data for my product and found out that one major concern was using third-party services like [Mongolab](https://mlab.com/), [Modulus](https://modulus.io/), [Heroku](http://heroku.com).

Are these products actually secure? I understand that you can only do so much to secure the services on the cloud where you get shared resources, but even from a cloud standpoint, do you guys feel comfortable using these services?

Answer (score 0):

I was checking with mlab and as far as you can got is:

1. ssl for connection protection,
2. authentication -

but there is one question left: **Is data at rest encrypted?**

If you need to comply with data protection acts (PCI) - this could be still an issue, but for other purposes I have no issues with mLab service.

Any comments welcome!